# A technical question on $df^*\omega=f^*d\omega$ for pullback of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am new to differential geometry and am learning it. My question here is just a technical one, but I am unable to figure it out and become confused after trying for quite a while, so I hope someone can help me out.

I am checking the statement $df^*\omega=f^*d\omega$ for a particular example, where $\omega$ is a differential form on a manifold $N$, and $f$ is a map from another manifold $M$ to $N$. From my explicit calculation, I find $df^*\omega\neq f^*d\omega$ in my case.

More precisely, consider a 2-manifold $N$ with coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$, and consider a 2-form $\omega=\sin\theta d\theta\wedge d\phi$ on $N$. So $N$ can be viewed as $S^2$, and $\omega$ can be viewed as the canonical volume form on $S^2$. In particular, $d\omega=0$.

Now consider a 3-manifold $M=N\times [0, 1]$, so the coordinates of $M$ can be taken as $\theta$, $\phi$, and $t\in [0, 1]$. Define a map $f: M\rightarrow N$ as: 
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\theta\\
\phi\\
t
\end{array}
\right)\in M
\stackrel{f}\longrightarrow
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\pi}{2}t+(1-t)\theta\\
(1-t)\phi
\end{array}
\right)\in N
\end{equation}

My goal is to check if $df^*\omega=f^*d\omega$, where the RHS vanishes because $d\omega=0$. However, I found that 
\begin{equation}
f^*\omega=\sin\theta(1-t)^2d\theta\wedge d\phi+\phi\sin\theta(1-t)dt\wedge d\theta+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)\sin\theta(1-t)dt\wedge d\phi
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
df^*\omega=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)\cos\theta(1-t)d\theta\wedge dt\wedge d\phi\neq 0=f^*d\omega
\end{equation}

On the other hand, one can prove that $df^*\omega=f^*d\omega$, so I think I have made a mistake. I appreciate if someone can let me know where my mistake is.

Comment: Wouldn't $f^* \omega$ be $\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}t + (1-t)\theta) d(\frac{\pi}{2}t + (1-t)\theta) \wedge d((1-t)\phi)$?  I don't see the $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t + (1-t)\theta)$ anywhere in your calculation.  (Also, if $N$ were really $S^2$, the map $N \times [0,1] \to N$ would not be well-defined - for example, f(0, \phi, t) \ne f(2\pi, \phi, t)$ in general.)

Comment: You get $f^*\omega=f^*(\sin\theta)f^*(d\theta\wedge d\phi)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}t+(1-t)\theta\right)f^*(d\theta\wedge d\phi)$. I think you forgot this step of the pullback. I haven't done the full calculation to check that this indeed solves the problem but it probably does.

Comment: By the way, you can take advantage of [sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/manifolds/sage/manifolds/differentiable/diff_form.html) to check computational results.

Comment: Yes, to reiterate. You have coordinates only on a subset of $S^2$. But that doesn't change your question. I agree that your initial computation of the pullback is flawed, so start by editing your post and correcting that, and do the rest of the computation accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I realized what my silly mistake was. As you pointed out, in my equation of $f^*\omega$ all $\sin\theta$ should really be $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}t+(1-t)\theta\right)$. After this correction, I indeed found $df^*\omega=f^*d\omega=0$.